# Java storing objects in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to store objects in a multidimensional array in an attempt to save each position in a game boards 'state', however after the loop which is supposed to set each instance to it's own parameters they all end up the same variables. Did I not link the correct array or set it up wrong?
There's also a lot of "square.something should be accessed in a static way".

Is square.var or World[x][y].var the correct way for referencing the objects variables?

```
public static void generateMap() {
    MapSquare[][] World = new MapSquare[10][10]; //2D array init.

    //Choose a square for the home position.
    Random homeRandom = new Random();
    int HomeX = homeRandom.nextInt(10);
    int HomeY = homeRandom.nextInt(10);

    //Chooses a key room.
    int KeyX = homeRandom.nextInt(10);
    int KeyY = homeRandom.nextInt(10);

    //Loop through the objects and set each's parameters.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
            MapSquare square = new MapSquare();
            //World[i][j] = square;

            //Calculate the level of the square from the distance to home.
            int distX = HomeX - i;
            int distY = HomeY - j;

            int CalcX = Math.abs(distX); //Convert to positive if negative.
            int CalcY = Math.abs(distY); //Convert to positive if negative.

            //Generate contents of the square.
            int newRandom = random.nextInt(5) + 1;

            switch(newRandom) {
            case 1: // Spawn a monster only.
                {
                square.monster = true;
                square.treasure = false;
                square.trap = false;
                square.home = false;
                square.peekable = false;
                square.key = false;
                square.mapLevel = CalcX + CalcY;

                //Generate the monsters stats.
                Monster monster = new Monster();
                monster.setLevel(square.mapLevel);
                monster.setMaxHealth(monster.getLevel() * 5);
                monster.setHealth(monster.getMaxHealth());
                monster.setDamage(monster.getLevel() * 2);
                break;
                }
            }
            }
        }

    //Generate home square.
    World[HomeX][HomeY].monster = false;
    World[HomeX][HomeY].treasure = false;
    World[HomeX][HomeY].trap = false;
    World[HomeX][HomeY].home = true;
    World[HomeX][HomeY].peekable = true;
    World[HomeX][HomeY].key = false;
    World[HomeX][HomeY].mapLevel = 0;
    World[HomeX][HomeY].visited = true;
    }
```

Comment: when you say random.nextInt(5) + 1 : you mean homeRandom.nextInt(5) +1 right ? In addition to that, I think you need to make your MapSquare class definition a little more standard. Modifying members directly is never a good idea. create setters for that.

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I see I defined another called random as well now which is redundant.

Comment: Is this line `//World[i][j] = square;` supposed to be commented out?

Comment: Yes that line is, being fairly new to this I was unsure and commented it out to see if anything changed which it didn't. MapSquare is basically only Getters and Setters right now other then init's. If I swap them to the Get's and Set's it says they should be accessed in a static way.

Comment: Don't tell me that you made everything `static` in the `MapSquare` class?  If so, then that's your problem.  Remove the `static` from each method and each field of that class, and put back that line that you commented out.  Then, go and read up on what `static` means.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought static meant usable outside the class by a non instantiated object, much like 'global' in game maker. Eclipse generated the Get's and Set's incorrectly as well after I added that and it works now, thanks for that. I'll do some more reading.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword basically means that a method can be used independently of a specific instance of the class it is in. Such as the `Math.abs(int i)` function you are using, you don’t have to create an instance of the `Math` class to use it.

If you intend to use a class to store data it is generally a bad idea to include static methods as they would not be able to access that data.